# Count changes of value in groupby aggregated data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with 5 columns that I need to count the value changes of in the hour of data the frame is grouped and aggregated by. The data is in 30 second intervals and my groupby aggregates that data to an hour, so within the 1 hour dataframe, there are 120 samples that I need to count the changes for in each column. Also, not every DeviceUUID has data in these columns, so there are lots of NaNs. A particular DeviceUUID will never have a NaN AND data in a column, It will either be Nan or always have a value between -13 and +13. If a DeviceUUID has NaN for 'Z_A', then 'Z_A_change-count' should also be NaN.

```
df_taps = df[['DeviceUUID', 'Timestamp', 'Z_A', 'Z_B', 'Z_C', 'X_CLOSED', 'X_OPEN', 'year', 'month', 'day', 'hour']]
df_taps.sort_values(by='Timestamp',inplace=True)
df_taps.head(2)

    DeviceUUID                              Timestamp               Z_A Z_B Z_C X_CLOSED    X_OPEN  year    month   day hour
0   374e3fe8-1e6d-467b-ac74-11ff3fcbf7fb    2020-11-04 05:00:07.321 NaN NaN NaN 0.0         1.0     2020    11  4   5
179 95f16a25-1024-4d77-8954-a88e30c89d6e    2020-11-04 05:00:07.321 NaN NaN 1.0 NaN         NaN     2020    11  4   5
```

I tried this:

```
df_taps['z_a_change_count'] = df_taps.groupby(['DeviceUUID', 'year', 'month', 'day', 'hour'])['Z_A'].rolling(2).apply(lambda x: x[0] != x[-1], raw=True).sum().astype(int)

df_taps['z_b_change_count'] = df_taps.groupby(['DeviceUUID', 'year', 'month', 'day', 'hour'])['Z_B'].rolling(2).apply(lambda x: x[0] != x[-1], raw=True).sum().astype(int)

df_taps['z_c_change_count'] = df_taps.groupby(['DeviceUUID', 'year', 'month', 'day', 'hour'])['Z_C'].rolling(2).apply(lambda x: x[0] != x[-1], raw=True).sum().astype(int)
...
```

But this gives me the same value for all the data, and it's wrong:

```
    DeviceUUID                              Timestamp               Z_A Z_B Z_C X_CLOSED    X_OPEN  year    month   day hour    z_a_change_count    z_b_change_count    z_c_change_count
0   374e3fe8-1e6d-467b-ac74-11ff3fcbf7fb    2020-11-04 05:00:07.321 NaN NaN NaN 0.0         1.0     2020    11      4   5       2                   3                   2
179 95f16a25-1024-4d77-8954-a88e30c89d6e    2020-11-04 05:00:07.321 NaN NaN 1.0 NaN         NaN     2020    11      4   5       2                   3                   2
```

I have also tried this:

```
df_taps_agg = df_taps.groupby(['DeviceUUID', 'year', 'month', 'day', 'hour']).agg(
    z_a_change_count=('Z_A', lambda x: sum(x.iloc[:-1] != x.shift(-1).iloc[:-1])),
    z_b_change_count=('Z_B', lambda x: sum(x.iloc[:-1] != x.shift(-1).iloc[:-1])),
    z_c_change_count=('Z_C', lambda x: sum(x.iloc[:-1] != x.shift(-1).iloc[:-1])),
    x_closed_change_count=('X_CLOSED', lambda x: sum(x.iloc[:-1] != x.shift(-1).iloc[:-1])),
    x_open_change_count=('X_OPEN', lambda x: sum(x.iloc[:-1] != x.shift(-1).iloc[:-1]))
)
df_taps_agg.reset_index(inplace=True)
df_taps_agg.head(2)
```

And get just the number of instances, not the sum of changes:

```
    DeviceUUID                              year    month   day hour    z_a_change_count    z_b_change_count    z_c_change_count    x_closed_change_count   x_open_change_count
0   00005f6c-8172-44a8-8e8f-6e36a012aef6    2020    11      4   5       119.0       119.0   0.0     119.0   119.0
1   01a74d94-5d69-4905-ab06-7935af09fcfc    2020    11      4   5       119.0       119.0   119.0   119.0   119.0
```

Answer (score 0):

So I battled through it, and came up with this that is working:

#### First, fillna:

```
df_taps[['Z_A', 'Z_B', 'Z_C']] = df_taps.groupby(['DeviceUUID'])['Z_A', 'Z_B','Z_C'].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(value=0))
```

#### Then, add columns that sum the count of diffs in the group:

```
df_taps_agg = df_taps.groupby(['DeviceUUID', 'year', 'month', 'day', 'hour']).agg(
      z_a_change_count=('Z_A', lambda x: (x.diff(periods=1) != 0).sum()-1),
      z_b_change_count=('Z_B', lambda x: (x.diff(periods=1) != 0).sum()-1),
      z_c_change_count=('Z_C', lambda x: (x.diff(periods=1) != 0).sum()-1)
        )
```

the `-1` is because the first record in a group will always be considered a change, so I offset it by one